# How to remove all css classes of all items of a <div> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div of nested ul/li items. each ul/li has a css class. Is there a **clean way** to remove all css class for all items inside this `<div>`?

**edit**: pls see here for code: http://jsfiddle.net/xjAkF/

Comment: Have you tried iterating the DOM elements and searching the attributes to find what you are looking for ? If so what problems are you having ?

Comment: my question asks for a clean way. what you mentioned will work but it's not clean nor fast.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv ul, #myDiv li').removeClass();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `.removeClass()` if this is passed with no parameters it will remove all classes.

You were missing the `#` in the selector.

See revised code, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/xjAkF/2/)

@AlienWebguy, Has a better solution that way it only removes from the ul & li within the given id.

Comment: Can you post code? That way we can see what is there and test solutions. I don't see why `.removeClass()` would not work.

Comment: i still see classes in the html...i'm using chrome. does that matter?

Comment: I think I was looking in the wrong place. I have the same code there now as @AlienWebGuy, but with your code

Answer (score 4):

To strip out classes from ALL children of an element, use find("*")

```
$('#divHtml').find("*").removeClass();
```

Comment: You could fine tune this as such: `var _list = $('ul,li'); $('#divHtml').find(_list).removeClass();`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#mydiv li, #mydiv ul").removeClass("Your class");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Replace #myDiv with a selector for your div.

```
$("#myDiv ul, #myDiv li").each(function() { this.className = ""; });
```

Comment: `.removeClass()` looks a bit cleaner, but I'll leave my answer to show that there's more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#item").removeAttr('class');
```